# Is a QT connection automatically deleted?

Tags: c++, qt

Is a QT connection constructed by the `connect()` statement automatically cleaned up, when its creator ( for example a QAction) is deleted, or must I do this on my own, by saving `connections` as instances of my class and deleting them in my destructor?

Given is the following example:

```
MYClass::MYClass() {
    connect(this, &QAction::triggered, this, &MYClass::clicked);
}
```

Comment: When `this` goes out of scope all signal / slot connections involving `this` will be removed.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for the destructor of `QObject` says

> All signals to and from the object are automatically disconnected

here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dtor.QObject

So no you don't have do disconnect your connections. When any QObject object is destructed it will clean this up for you.